# What environment variable to set for "android update project -p ..."

Tags: android, windows, ant

I'm trying to set up ANT for my Android project. According to the Android website, the command to use is

```
android update project -p name
```

Unfortunately, the command "android" is not available on my command line (Windows 7).
Can you please tell me what kind of environment variables do I have to set up? The SDK is located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, I assume I will need that.

Do I just have to extend "path" or is there the need to create new variables (something like "JAVA_HOME", but for android).

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools

are both valuable to have on the path.  I don't remember which has the `android` binary, but, with both, you will definitely get it.  With both you will also get `adb` and `progaurd`.

And also, extend PATH don't create a new one.